# Redux reducer state was not updating with previous state while using hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hi  currently i am creating a project using hooks with redux.

while every time i trigger a new request ...state was not maintaining the previous data.so please help upon this .

```
const initialState = {
  isLoaded: false,


  followData:{},
  FollowerCountData:{}

}
export default function followReducer(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    
      case allActions.FETCH_FOLLOW_DATA:
        return action;
      case allActions.RECIEVE_FOLLOW_DATA:
        return {
          ...state,
          followData: action.payload,
        };

        case allActions.FETCH_FOLLOWER_COUNT:
          return action;
        case allActions.RECIEVE_FOLLOWER_COUNT:
          return {
            ...state,
            FollowerCountData: action.payload,
          };
    default: return state;
  } 
  
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning action from the reducer??i suppose you want to return current state instead right?

Comment: yeah actually i am returning current state, that state was not updated with previous data.Thanks for asking

Comment: your reducer should only return the state, but you're returning action in some of your cases

Comment: Yeah you should return state not action

Comment: Actually while receiving the data i am updating my state and coming to actions i am returning those actions at the time of dispatch only.